# Centos add multiple interfaces from file to VLANs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I write script, that will create CentOS interfaces from file with list of IP addresses. In loop, i create file, next action, i add data for centos interfaces. Look:

```
from=/root/ip
inter=`cat /proc/net/dev | grep "eth0:\|venet0" |  awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/://g'`
eth=`ifconfig | grep $inter | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed "s/$inter://g"`
echo "Last number of interface: $eth"

if [ "$eth" == "eth0" ]; then
 eth_temp="-1"
else
 eth_temp=$eth
fi

if [ "$inter" == "eth0" ]; then
 echo "Name of interface: $inter"
 echo "Add IP to interfaces"
if [ -f $from ]; then
 for IP_TO_ETH in `grep -v ^# $from`; do
 eth_temp=$(($eth_temp+1))
 cent_int=`touch /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$inter:$eth_temp`
 cat >> $cent_int <<END
DEVICE=eth0:$eth_temp
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO='static'
IPADDR=$IP_TO_ETH
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

END
  done
 else
 echo "File does not exist"
fi
elif [ "$inter" == "venet0" ]; then
 echo "Name of interface: $inter"
 echo "This interface from OpenVZ. Not need to add"
 else
 echo "Other name of inteface"
fi
```

All ok. But it is not working. When i start bash/sh -x, i receive this:

```
cent.sh: line 28: $cent_int: ambiguous redirect
+ for IP_TO_ETH in '`grep -v ^# $from`'
+ eth_temp=61
++ touch /root/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:61
+ cent_int=
+ cat
cent.sh: line 28: $cent_int: ambiguous redirect
+ for IP_TO_ETH in '`grep -v ^# $from`'
+ eth_temp=62
++ touch /root/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:62
+ cent_int=
+ cat
```

Where i have error ? Please help. In ubuntu it is simply, because all will write in one file. But in CentOS, it is too difficult for me.

Comment: `touch` doesn't produce any output, so `cent_int=\`touch ...` ` doesn't assign anything to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
variable=`command`
```

it sets the variable to the output of the command. But `touch` doesn't produce any output, so

```
cent_int=`touch /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$inter:$eth_temp`
```

assigns an empty string to `cent_int`. I think what you want is:

```
cent_int=/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-$inter:$eth_temp
```

You don't need to use `touch`, since writing to the file with `cat >> $cent_int` will create the file if it doesn't already exist.